# javascript If Else block is jumping to Else, even when the Conditional is marking true

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to perform an operation based on a true or false value from a checkbox.  Using an If:Else statment I test if the checkbox value is "true", onfurtunetly even if the checkbox value marks "true" its going into the Else section of my statment.

Can anyone please explain to me the reason for this?

```
        var CheckedBoxs = $(stepTitle + " input:checkbox");
        for (var val in CheckedBoxs) {
            if (val.toString() === "length") {
                break;
            } //End IF
            if (CheckedBoxs[val].value === "true") {
                OneUp = parseInt(val) + 1;
                var PriceTag = "  -$";
                PriceTag += HiddenInput[OneUp].name.substring(HiddenInput[OneUp].name.indexOf(":") + 1, HiddenInput[OneUp].name.length);
                Lbls[val].innerHTML = Lbls[val].innerHTML + '<span class="PriceChange">' + PriceTag + "</span>";
            } else {
                OneUp = parseInt(val) + 1;
                var PriceTag = "  +$";
                PriceTag += HiddenInput[OneUp].name.substring(HiddenInput[OneUp].name.indexOf(":") + 1, HiddenInput[OneUp].name.length);
                Lbls[val].innerHTML = Lbls[val].innerHTML + '<span class="PriceChange">' + PriceTag + "</span>";
            }//End If
        }//End For
```

I have seen many question related to If:Else statments, but was unable to find one that invloved a checkbox, apologies if this is a repeat.

Comment: I have tried useing true and "true",  in intelisence: .value returns as a string and .checked returns as a boolean.

Comment: `CheckedBoxs[val].is(":checked")`

Comment: CheckedBoxs[val].is(":checked")  Tried this unfortunettly it returns: undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things

First

`for (var val in CheckedBoxs) {`

that is not how to loop over an array; only use that loop over properties of an object literal.

Second

`if (CheckedBoxs[val].value === "true") {`

should be

`if (CheckedBoxs[val].checked) {`

[Edit, fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W9Zmu/1/)

Comment: Also, if they really are checkboxes, then the "value" attribute will be constant; probably what should be tested is the "checked" property.

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking the "checked" state? `CheckedBoxs[val].is(":checked");`?

Comment: var CheckedBoxs = $(stepTitle + " input:checkbox"); Does this not produce an literal object? sure doesnt look like an array to me.

and as stated above CheckedBoxs[val].is(":checked");?  this does not work.

Comment: @DirtyRedz That produces an array-like **object**. Nonetheless, you should loop with `.each()`